# Find link element by URL and add a class using PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to add a class to the current item using PHP. I have a static navigation that looks like this:

```
<ul id="myList">
  <li><a href="page1.php">Page One</a></li>
  <li><a href="page2.php">Page Two</a></li>
  <li><a href="page3.php">Page Three</a></li>
</ul>
```

The logic I want to follow is:

1. Grab the URL and get the last section, store it in a `$path` variable.
2. Find a link from within `myList` that has the SRC attribute that matches `$path`
3. Add a class of `.current` to the attribute.

I've already sorted point one with this:

```
$path = basename( parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH) );
```

But I'm new to PHP so I'm not sure how to go about points 2 & 3. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

The "cheap" way to do it would be as follows:

```
// assuming $html is your code
$html = str_replace($path,$path.'" class="current',$html);
```

The proper way would be to use an HTML parser.

The correct way would be to put it there in the first place when generating your source.

Answer (score 0):

Just update your "static" navigation to be a dynamic one.

```
$links = array(
    array('link' => 'page1.php', 'text' => 'Page One'),
    array('link' => 'page2.php', 'text' => 'Page Two'),
    array('link' => 'page3.php', 'text' => 'Page Three')
);
$path = basename( parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH) );
echo '<ul id="myList">'
foreach ($links as $link) {
    $class = '';
    if ($link['link'] == $path) {
        $class = 'current';
    }
    echo "<li><a href=\"$link[link]\" class=\"$class\">$link[text]</a></li>";
}
echo "</ul>";
```

This situation is actually what PHP was originally designed for.  If the above looks a bit ugly to you, you may want to look into using a template system.  There are many popular and mature ones out there.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Due to being a such a novice, I'm trying to avoid using a template system, or anything overly complicated just yet. The website is quite simple, in that it's only <10 pages which have static content. I'm mainly utilizing PHP so that I pull in repeating content.